# PhantomJS не подключается

Tags: asp.net-core, phantomjs, nuget

В Visual Studio nuget package manager подключил `PhantomJS 2.1.1`
Но в namespace `OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS` **нет!**
Также в пакетах установлен Selenium.PhantomJS.WebDriver
Весь интернет перерыл уже, ничего не нашел. Его просто нет в namespace.
**Как быть?**

Answer (score 0):

Ответ для тех, кто в дальнейшем будет искать: `"Как подключить PhantomJS на C# ASP.Net Core"`
Уже никак! Его поддержка прекратилась в 2018 году. И при том, что в nuget package manager он еще присутствует *(с более 2М скачиваний)*, но в нем отсутстует утилита важная для работы.
Вобщем нашел решение для парсинга через `headless chromedriver`.
Для парсинга динамических страниц через браузер без GUI-графической оболочки.